# Laravel Cashier not storing card version 10.1

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am creating a new app using Cashier 10.1. In the past I would send a token from Stripe to the subscription function when registering a user with a subscription. Now it says it takes a Payment Method (id). I am registering a payment method with Stripe and passing that to my controller but it returns the error "*This customer has no attached payment source*". I read the docs but it only gives an example of how to add a subscription to a current user by passing to the view `$user->createSetupIntent()`. Below is the code for when a user registers:

Component

```
       pay() {
            this.isLoading = true;

            if (this.form.payment_method == "cc") {
                let that = this;
                this.stripe
                    .createPaymentMethod({
                        type: "card",
                        card: that.card
                    })
                    .then(result => {
                        this.form.stripePayment = result.paymentMethod.id;
                        this.register();
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            } else {
                this.register();
            }
        },

        register() {
            this.form
                .post("/register")
                .then(data => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    if (data.type == "success") {
                        this.$swal({
                            type: "success",
                            title: "Great...",
                            text: data.message,
                            toast: true,
                            position: "top-end",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        });

                        setTimeout(() => {
                            // window.location.replace(data.url);
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
```

RegisterController

```
protected function create(request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'agree' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'phone' => $request['phone'],
            'city' => $request['city'],
            'state' => $request['state'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);

        if ($request['subscription_type'] == 'premier' && $request['payment_method'] == 'cc') {

            $user->newSubscription('default',  env('STRIPE_PLAN_ID'))->create($request->input('stripePayment'), [
                'email' => $request['email'],
            ]);
        }



        if ($user) {
            $user->assignRole('subscriber');



            Auth::login($user);

            return response()->json([
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => 'you are all set.',
                'url' => '/dashboard'
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good [article](https://www.seismicpixels.com/creating-a-laravel-saas-framework-part-6/)) explaining the new setup finally. Basically when I show my registration view I now create a new User and pass the intent there. I kept thinking the user had to be saved already, not just created. So if anyone else wants to do it:

Show the view

Registration Controller

```
public function show()
    {
        $user = new User;

        return view('auth.register', [
            'intent' => $user->createSetupIntent()
        ]);
    }
```

Pass the intent to my Vue component

```
<register-form stripe-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}" stripe-intent="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
            </register-form>
```

Add stripe elements to a div:

```
 mounted() {
        // Create a Stripe client.
        this.stripe = Stripe(this.stripeKey);

        // Create an instance of Elements.
        var elements = this.stripe.elements();

        var style = {
            base: {
                color: "#32325d",
                fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
                fontSize: "16px",
                "::placeholder": {
                    color: "#aab7c4"
                }
            },
            invalid: {
                color: "#fa755a",
                iconColor: "#fa755a"
            }
        };

        // Create an instance of the card Element.
        this.card = elements.create("card", { style: style });

        // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
        this.card.mount("#card-element");
    },
```

process the data

```
pay() {
            this.isLoading = true;

            if (this.form.payment_method == "cc") {
                this.setupCard();
            } else {
                this.register();
            }
        },

        setupCard() {
            this.stripe
                .handleCardSetup(this.stripeIntent, this.card, {
                    payment_method_data: {
                        billing_details: { name: this.form.name }
                    }
                })
                .then(data => {
                    this.form.stripePayment = data.setupIntent.payment_method;
                    if (this.form.stripePayment) this.register();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },

        register(setupIntent) {
            this.form
                .post("/register")
                .then(data => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    if (data.type == "success") {
                        this.$swal({
                            type: "success",
                            title: "Great...",
                            text: data.message,
                            toast: true,
                            position: "top-end",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        });

                        setTimeout(() => {
                            window.location.replace(data.url);
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
```

Save the user

Registration Controller

```
protected function create(request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'agree' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'phone' => $request['phone'],
            'city' => $request['city'],
            'state' => $request['state'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);

        if ($request['subscription_type'] == 'premier' && $request['payment_method'] == 'cc') {

            $user->newSubscription('default',  env('STRIPE_PLAN_ID'))->create($request->input('stripePayment'), [
                'email' => $request['email'],
            ]);
        }



        if ($user) {
            $user->assignRole('subscriber');



            Auth::login($user);

            return response()->json([
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => 'you are all set.',
                'url' => '/dashboard'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cashier has updated the way it interacts with Stripe due to [Strong Customer Authentication (SCA)](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication). This means card payments require a different user experience, namely 3D Secure, in order to meet SCA requirements. It may be beneficial to read-up on the [Payment Intents API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) on Stripe and you may be able to work around this by first creating the payment intent with a direct interaction with Stripe and then attaching it to your Laravel user.

The simple solution may be to have a multi step registration process:

- **Step 1:** Collect customer details and create user on Laravel and Stripe
- **Step 2:** Create the payment intent `$user->createSetupIntent()` and collect payment details and save to customer.
- **Step 3:** Subscribe user to the Cashier Plan

Comment: Is this really how it works now? If we have to break up the registration process to first create a user and then take billing info by either loading a new page or having to submit a new form it always creates the possibility for the user to exit out before the process is complete. Thus if they reload the page and try to input their email again to sign up its taken, then they need to login to see they havent paid, and then fill out a form. Having it take the CC on user creation is a lot better experience.

Comment: @Packy in my experience with Cashier 10, this is process I've had to follow. Would seem that it would push you to offering a free trial without the need for a credit card. I've created customers. It would appear to be possible to perform your preferred user flow using the vanilla Stripe PHP Library. `Customer::create()` only requires a description to create, then create a payment intent for the signup and assign the customer once collected their details.

Comment: I actually got a different way to work with no step forms. See below